# log4net debug selective filter

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to ask if the log4net framework can perform selective filter to display a DEBUG item for a certain condition only? Currently I have a java application that expels a lot of DEBUG logs. If you turn the threshold value to debug, the log rotates to the max allowable files rotation within half a day. I am forced to set the threshold to info but I would like to still show selected debug value log.

Can this be done without code change? just a change in the log4j.properties file?

Say for example, I would like to display a certain DEBUG item with a certain keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know you could do it but reading the documentation for [Filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html), it seems they might accomplish what you want.